# Loop through data to integrate in blocks: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, octave

I am currently trying to implement a loop in Matlab/Octave wherein data from a file is read, stored in an array and then integrated in batches of 1600 points ( each data point is spaced at 10 ns). 
I understand the logic of what I need to do, but am unable to code it. any help would be appreciated.

```
trace_int = zeros(320000,1);
trace_c = zeros(200,1);
trace = dlmread('trace_all.dat',' ',[0,0,320000,1]);
while i = 1:200
    trace_i(i,:) = trace(1+1599*(i-1):1:1600*(i));
    trace_c(i,:) = trapz(trace_i(i));
end
```

this is what the data looks like

```
20 1484  
30 1484  
40 1483  
50 1484  
60 1484  
70 1484  
80 1483  
90 1483
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a loop:

```
% create sample data
trace = [20 1484; 30 1454; 40 1493; 50 1414; 60 1404; 70 1494; 80 1473; 90 483];

n = 4; % this would be 1600 in your case
trace_c = trapz (reshape (trace (:, 2), n, []))
```

returns:

```
trace_c =
    4396.0   3910.5
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a touch! Note, you're not accounting for the X data in the integration (neither was the OP to be fair) but since it's of constant interval we could just divide by dx at the end

Comment: @Wolfie Since he said the space is constant 10ns... And thanks for the edit, I always forget that MATLAB can't handle # as comment

Comment: Yeah simplifies things. No worries, I often mistakenly use `'` when I'm in full VB mode

Comment: sorry, when I input this code it returns the following error - "
error: reshape: SIZE is not divisible by the product of known dimensions (= 1600)". the problem is my data is continuous, the next pulse also starts from 0 and ends with 16000. there are about a billion such pulses.

Comment: Your data isn't a multiple of 1600. For example, if `n=5` in the above example it wouldn't work. You can break up your data, and then integrate the remainder after:

 `lastOfBatch = n*floor(size(trace,1)/n);[trapz(reshape(trace(1:lastOfBatch, 2), n, [])),trapz(reshape(trace(lastOfBatch+1:end,2),rem(size(trace,1),n),[]))]`

Comment: The code you've written here works, but it doesn't give the correct values.
for instance the code gives values of around 4*10^3, while the actual answer lies around 3*10^6.
also could you clarify what you mean by this statement  - "Your data isn't a multiple of 1600" ? (I'm using 3200000 data points)
thanks

Comment: I meant that error describes your input as "not divisible" by 1600. Step through with the debugger, and see the values you have at the code, it may not be what you think.

Comment: @Miscellaneous you wrote above that the size of your input is 320000, which is a multiple of 1600. Try to add more info to your question and/or create a full MCVE or upload your raw data (for example .gz compressed)

Comment: @John the issue resolved was resolved when I took a transpose of the resized matrix. Thanks for all the help :)
I had 2 questions though - (1) can someone take me through what was done in the last line of the code    `[trapz(reshape(trace(1:lastOfBatch, 2), n, [])),trapz(reshape(trace(lastOfBatch+1:end,2),rem(size(trace‌​,1),n),[]))]`   .  (2) if I were to use a loop how would I go about it (this would help me in my further projects). Thanks